# SwiftUI: NavigationBarItem leading does not show up

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

With this code, why does the navigationBarItem not show up?
The view gets called for within a sheet, but that did not matter before ...

```
struct ChangePasswordView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) private var presentationMode

    @State private var passwordNew = ""
    @State private var passwordNewAgain = ""

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            changePassword
        }
        .navigationBarItems(leading: backButton)
        .navigationBarItems(trailing: finishButton)
    }

    var backButton: some View {
        Button(action: { self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss() }) {
            Text("Cancel")
        }
    }

    var finishButton: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.changePasswordGlobally()
            self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }) {
            Text("Apply")
        }
        .disabled(self.passwordNew.isEmpty || self.passwordNew != self.passwordNewAgain)
        .disableAutocorrection(true)
    }
}
```

As you can see in the following screenshots, the navigationBarItem that should be leading does not show up:

[image: Screenshot with the problem!]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For both side items use this variant (tested as worked with Xcode 11.2 / iOS 13.2):

```
ScrollView {
    changePassword
}
.navigationBarItems(leading: backButton, trailing: finishButton)
```

Comment: Can confirm, doing it with two calls to `navigationBarItems` one for leading and one for trailing does not work!

Comment: Yes. Its not working if two calls in iOS14. same is working for iOS 15 :)